# Looking for Solution to Export/Import Dynamic Content For Translation

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

We have a DNN 7 site that needs to be translated to Spanish and we need some way of exporting all the dynamic content so it can be sent to a translation service and then importing the translated text back into DNN.

Ran across this blog post: http://blog.globalizationpartners.com/dotnetnuke-7-internationalization.aspx but could not locate the second/follow up article which according to this post was to discuss the export/import of DNN dynamic content for translation.

Has anyone gotten this to work? Our translators use special tools and typically do not log onto CMS systems and make edits directly.

Answer (score -1):

I am using [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/) for that. It is not specific to DNN, but you can handle resx files, export them to and import them from Excel spreadsheets... I find it quite useful.

Happy DNNing!
Michael

Comment: Not what I am looking for. Again, content is inside of DNN and not in resx files.

Comment: Oh sorry... Somehow I missed the fact that you want to export dynamic content. This seems to be a bit difficult to me as the way the content is stored depends on the used extensions, and this could be very different.